# Arrive in the US with a Tourist Visa before Student Visa starts

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, f1-visas

My girlfriend will be starting college in the US in January. Is it possible for her to get a tourist visa so that she can be here more than 30 days before the start of her classes?

Comment: @Ozzy it might not be a duplicate, depending on the purpose of her arrival before the 30-day period.